# How to get Robot Framework to log python methods called in python?

Tags: logging, function-pointers, robotframework

Robot

```
Test Robot
    [Tags]                             example
    Test
```

Python:

```
def robot_keyword(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        logger.console(function.__name__)
        return BuiltIn().run_keyword(function.__name__)
    return wrapper

def test():
    # BuiltIn().run_keyword('hello')
    hello()

@robot_keyword
def hello():
    logger.console('hi')
```

Because run_keyword does not pass the function pointer and tries to call hello() again, I hit a loop.

> Maximum limit of started keywords exceeded.

Has anyone found a way to have robot log functions like 'hello()' in the robot logs?

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect in your code example. Are all of the functions inside the definition of `robot_keyword`? Please fix the indentation.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. I can get the traces. I wanted the collapsable html tree from nested keywords. Just so I don't get a huge flat trace for large python keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Tracebacks are available with the DEBUG log level.

From the robot framework user guide section [Debugging problems](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#debugging-problems):

> If the log file does not provide enough information by default, it is possible to execute tests with a lower log level. For example tracebacks showing where in the code the failure occurred are logged using the DEBUG level, and this information is invaluable when the problem is in an individual library keyword.